# why toast message not showing in marshmallow 6.0.1 while showing it lower than 6.0

Tags: android

i am using toast messaging ; toast message was showing well below marshmallow 6.0 but for marshmallow 6.0 and 6.+ toast not showing, push notification also not showing too. please solve this.

for Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "You can use this service once between every 8 hours", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

for pushNotification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_24dp).setContentTitle("Friends in danger").setContentText("Save friends in danger.");
//Intent resultIntent=new Intent(context,DangerFriendsMapsActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(DangerFriendsMapsActivity.class);
taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(toDangerIntent);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: same result i have tried with that

Comment: Are all toasts not showing or only this one?

Comment: @madhankumar `this` is a context. Don't use `getBaseContext()` unless you absolutely understand what it does. And this is not the place to use it.

Comment: *Notification* is a UI element. *Push notification* or *push message* is a means of transport. If neither toast nor notification are shown that means your code didn't execute so far. I.e. Your toast and notification are correct. Problem is in the event that's supposed to trigger the toast or notification.

Comment: no toast nor notification not showing in the app while running api 23, but working well below 23. @greenapps EugenPechanec

Comment: i have tried the action in long keyPress option which also working well below 23

Answer (score 3):

i solved my problem by myself, goto 
Sound & notification from mobile settings. Next, scroll to the app for which you want to adjust notification settings..
enable it

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,Its working in my marshmallow mobile

```
android.widget.Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "!! Message here !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: same result...,