# Toast message not working for one user using Marshmallow 6.0.1

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-toast

I have an app in use by some users, and one user with android 6.0.1 don't see any Toast.makeText() message in the entire app, while
for any other user it works fine.

I have found [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067977/why-toast-message-not-showing-in-marshmallow-6-0-1-while-showing-it-lower-than-6), but with no help.

Is there a reason for it? Something about this specific android version?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the user has blocked all notifications for your app in Android Settings -> Apps -> {Your app} -> Notifications, that setting will also block Toast messages.